# Take exact root of value

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, pseudocode

I'd like to know how you can take the exact n-th root of a number (in any programming language). When I use a physical calculator, I can type something like `sqrt(12)` (nicely formatted of course) and get as a result `2 sqrt(3)`. How can I achieve this not only with square roots but any type of root when representing a number as `numerator` and `denominator`. Of course, I would have to use another representation, but I don't have any idea how this works in general.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the calculator do it then? I wonder why it's even capable of doing that

Comment: This is definitely possible. I can see this being a interesting interview question.

Comment: So, in pseudocode, for any `x^(1/n)`, you want to decompose that into the factors of `x`. Then, going through each of those factors, `f_i`, determine if you can take `f_i^(1/n)` with no remainder, a `%` calculation. If so, that result becomes part of the output, otherwise you keep the original `f_i^(1/n)`. But I think that this question should be moved to [CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This looks like a perfectly valid question for SO to me; that's what the `language-agnostic`, `pseudo-code` and `algorithm` tags are for.

Comment: May I suggest a title like "simplify n-th root of integer"?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt this is an efficient way, but it would work. Assuming you want to take the `n`<sup>th</sup> root of some number `m`:

1. Calculate the *prime factorization* `m = p1a1 * p2a2 * ... * pxax`.
2. For each `1 <= i <= x` let `ki = ai div n` and `ri = ai mod n`.
3. The part that gets factored out is then `p1k1 * p2k2 * ... * pxkx`.

   The part that remains "under the root" is `p1r1 * p2r2 * ... * pxrx`.

The first step is the only tricky one. Once you have found all prime factors of `m` it is just a matter of looping over those factors and dividing out the multiples of `n`.

Comment: Wouldn't this be the same, and simpler?: `ki=ai div n`, `r1=ai mod n`

Comment: @JeffY yeah, I kinda wrote the definition of div and mod there, right? I'll update.

Comment: Consider the fourth root of 50 -- it's sqrt(5) * 4root(2). To get there, one can add an iterative fourth step to Vincent's steps which extracts divisor-roots of n out, much the same way Vincent's steps extract out the n-th roots of m.

Comment: @kaganar great addition! Didn't think of that simplification

Comment: Isn't prime factorisation overkill if you're just looking for the largest integer whose n-th power divides the number ? Granted, my method uses a bit of brute force, but with some additional optimisation I bet it's faster than prime factorisation.

Comment: @m69 yes, you could factor out `p_i^n` instead of `p_i` and it would be much faster. However, if you want to consider kanagar's addition, you should also compute `GCD(n, r_i)` to factor out some more. I think that would be easiest if you have prime factors already (depends on `n` too).

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure @Kanagar's idea really falls under "simplification" of a root. Have a look at my updated algorithm; I can't see any advantage in getting the prime factors. In theory it could be improved further by going high-to-low, like in the first version, but then you have to take a floating-point n-th root, which looks too much like cheating, and is probably slower.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the n-th root of a number, the algorithm shouldn't do prime factorisation, but rather "n-th power factorisation", i.e. look for the largest n-th power inside the root, which you can then move outside the root. For example: the 3rd root of 250 equals the third root of 2 x 125; since 125 is the third power of 5, you can move it out of the root and get: 5 times the third root of 2.

Algorithm: take the floating-point n-th root of the number, and round it down, then check this and all smaller integers until you find the largest integer whose n-th power divides the number; then divide the number by the n-th power and move the integer out of the root.

This javascript example shows a basic implementation; you could clean it up further by printing 1<sup>1/root</sup> simply as 1; further optimisation is undoubtedly possible.

```js
function integerRoot(number, root) {
    var base = number, factor = 1;
    var max = Math.floor(Math.pow(base, 1/root));
    for (var i = max; i > 1; i--) {
        var power = Math.pow(i, root);
        if (base % power == 0) {
            base /= power;
            factor *= i;
            break;
        }
    }
    document.write(number + "<SUP>1/" + root + "</SUP> = " + 
                   factor + " &times; " + base + "<SUP>1/" + root + "</SUP><BR>");
}

integerRoot(25, 3);
integerRoot(27, 3);
integerRoot(81, 3);
integerRoot(135, 3);
integerRoot(375, 3);
integerRoot(8*27*64*17, 3);
```

UPDATE: This is a more efficient version; I haven't yet taken negative numbers into account, though, so there's definitely room for further improvement.

```js
function simplifyRoot(radicand, degree) {
    var factor = 1, base = 1, power;
    while ((power = Math.pow(++base, degree)) <= radicand) {
        while (radicand % power == 0) {
            factor *= base;
            radicand /= power;
        }
    }
    return {factor: factor, radicand: radicand, degree: degree};
}

var radicand = 8*27*36*64*125*216, degree = 3;
var simplified = simplifyRoot(radicand, degree);

document.write(radicand + "<SUP>1/" + degree + "</SUP> = " + 
    simplified.factor + " &times; " + simplified.radicand + "<SUP>1/" + simplified.degree + "</SUP><BR>");
```